# InfluxDB subquery and where clause

Tags: subquery, where-clause, influxdb

I'm attempting to operate a where clause on a resultset, I think it should work (according to [the InfluxDB website](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/tldr-influxdb-tech-tips-march-30-2017/)) however, it isn't. The query looks like;

`SELECT (cumulative_sum(mean("ap"))/1000*24 - cumulative_sum(mean("ep"))/1000*24) as "cs", mean("gs") as "mgs" FROM (SELECT "ExpectedAverage EP" as "ep" FROM /^$EquipmentName$/ WHERE ("ModelName" =~ /^$ModelName$/)  and $timeFilter), (SELECT "Field GS" as "gs", "Field AP" as "ap" FROM /^$EquipmentName$/ where $timeFilter) GROUP BY time(1d) fill(null)`

which works, and returns two result sets along with time, "cs" and "mgs".

Modifying the query by adding a **where clause**;

`WHERE "mgs" >= 0 GROUP BY time(1d) fill(null)`

So the complete query looks like;

`SELECT (cumulative_sum(mean("ap"))/1000*24 - cumulative_sum(mean("ep"))/1000*24) as "cs", mean("gs") as "mgs" FROM (SELECT "ExpectedAverage EP" as "ep" FROM /^$EquipmentName$/ WHERE ("ModelName" =~ /^$ModelName$/)  and $timeFilter), (SELECT "Field GS" as "gs", "Field AP" as "ap" FROM /^$EquipmentName$/ where $timeFilter) WHERE "mgs" >= 0 GROUP BY time(1d) fill(null)`

Brings nothing back, but no error (**mgs is always greater than or equal to 0**). Changing the where clause to 1 > 0 works, and brings back the result sets as expected. Splitting out the subquery to three clauses also doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated!

(The final aim is to be able to query where "mgs" > 0)

Comment: I've had the case where my outer `WHERE` clause was being applied in the inner query, which was a bug, not sure if it's fixed. Could it be that? Since you don't have `mgs` in the inner queries the condition will always be false; Influx does not complain about it because it's schema is flexible. Series may exist one second and be gone the next, and then back again.

Comment: @NikolayManolov I guess it depends when the 'where' is applied. I did also try adding the where in the subqueries (which I would have thought should also work), but that brings back no results as well. Did you find a way around this?